# Typescript, Window type augmentation not working

Tags: typescript

`root/global.d.ts`:

```
import {GGMessage} from "./GGMessage";
export {}

declare global {
    export interface Window {onWebsocketsMessageReceived: (data: ArrayBuffer) => GGMessage | null}
}
```

`root/src/webSocketProxy.ts`:

```
window.onWebsocketsMessageReceived
```

**PROBLEM - The line above yields:**

```
Error:(30, 36) TS2339: Property 'onWebsocketsMessageReceived' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.
```

Why is that so? Also, I am *pretty* sure the entire thing worked just a while ago, though I'm unable to determine the exact changes. Nevertheless, the relevant (provided) things do look to be written properly.

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
     "sourceMap": true,
     "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
     "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
  }
}
```

Comment: try to declare the window stuff on a script file at the start of your program, not in a `d.ts` file. It did the trick for me.

Comment: It has probably something to do with some breaking changes introduced in TypeScript 3.5: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-5/#breaking-changes. Did you upgrade from an older version recently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just declare the `Window` interface in your `root/global.d.ts`

```
declare interface Window {
 onWebsocketsMessageReceived: (data: ArrayBuffer) => GGMessage | null
}
```

it will be auto merged into the definition in `lib.dom.d.ts`.